# 15th power Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'd appreciate some help (a hint) for the following. 
If $x,y>1$ are so that $2x^2-1=y^{15}$ then $x$ is a multiple of $5$.

Don't know if this helps but the equation can be rewritten as $2x^2=(y^5+1)(y^2-y+1)(y^8+y^7-y^5-y^4-y^3+y+1)$

Comment: Why do you expect this to be true in the first place?

Comment: It's a problem. You have to show that x must be a multiple of 5.

Comment: Why do "you have to show"? Is it somehow related to your research in mathematics? Is there a connection with some other, more general question?

Comment: @user47395 you are not allowed to post homeworks here except in exceptional circumstances, like if the problem is well motivated or you can show that you are in berkeley

Comment: "or you can show that you are in berkeley." Wait, what?

Comment: @NoahS please do not continue meta-debates here.

Comment: Note that y will be odd, that h=(y^15 + 1)/(y+1) will be odd, and that gcd(y+1, h) divides 15.  If x is not a multiple of 5, then h and (y+1)/2 are either both squares or both 3 times a square.  You might take this hint with you to another forum.  Note also that (1,1) is a solution to the equation, so directly working mod n for some integer n will not be enough.  Good luck at the other forum.  Gerhard "Look At Some Texts Too" Paseman, 2014.02.24

Comment: You may need more to solve the problem (I haven't worked it through).  However, unless you change the question to make yourself smell like a serious researcher (so far you haven't), this forum is not the best place for it.  Gerhard "Often Has A Stuffy Nose" Paseman, 2014.02.24

Comment: Does $ 2x^2−1=y^{15} $ even have integer solutions? I just checked for first $ 100000000 $ natural $y$'s and found nothing ($x $ wasn't integer number). I'll try to proof that they don't exist (or they do), and if I success I'll write here. I mean, if I prove that statement about $ x,y>1 $ that satisfies an equation is false (because such x,y don't exist), then from false everything can emerge, thus implication will be true :)